# View size and position for iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7

I am having a weird problem in iOS7 and iOS6. If anyone could help me out.

Problem : 
- in iOS6 and earlier the view coordinates starts after NavigationBar but in iOS7 the view coordinates starts after StatusBar and calculate NavigationBar in the View. So what ever looks fine in iOS6 will spoil in iOS7. The NavigationBar hides the top 44 px of the View in iOS7.

I tried to search on internet but could not find any proper solution. I can pragmatically arrange the views by iOS7 condition. But I know its not a proper way to do it. So if you know how to resolve this issue, please guide me. I have attached 2 screenshots one is from iOS6 and the other is iOS7 so you get a better idea of the problem.

[image: iOS7]
[image: iOS6]

Comment: Questions about beta software are automatically too localized. However, if you are starting with iOS 7, you should check the transition guide, WWDC 2013 videos and apple developer forums. The "problem" you are having is mentioned everywhere, including the "solution".

Comment: Hi Sulthan, thanks for the comment, but if you know the answer you should post the answer. If you have the specific link you can also post it that will help me as well as others.

Comment: Answering the question would breach my non-disclosure agreement (NDA) with Apple. You have already breached your NDA by asking the question and posting the screenshots, by the way. I cannot add any links because all information is available only for registered Apple Developers.

Answer (score 0):

Although iOS 7 is still in beta phase. But according to current docs, you can check the version and load your components accordingly. See this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1) ( You need to login to developer portal first ).

```
 if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
     // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
  } else {
     // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for comment, is there any other way from Interface Builder where we can set the view coordinate always starts after NavigationBar ?

Comment: I don't think there is any such way till now. one workaround would be to put one extra navigation bar over there and make it hidden true or false according to the OS.